# applications of uncountability of $π_1(\mathbb{R}^2−\mathbb{Q}^2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there any application on the fact that $π_1(\mathbb{R}^2−\mathbb{Q}^2)$ is uncountable?

Comment: This post may have some of the information you want in its analysis. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/pi-1-mathbb-r2-mathbb-q2-is-uncountable

Comment: Your further question baffles me... It is probably a useless piece of knowledge apart from the interesting fact that one can construct in suc a simple way such a complicated space. But what did you expect, really? Applications of that to what?

Comment: usefulness.. maybe its good for proving something...