# What's the fundamental group of $E^2\setminus Q^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Here $E^2$ is the two-dimensional Euclid space and $Q$ is the set of all rational numbers. Regard $E^2\setminus Q^2$ as a subspace of $E^2$. So what's its fundamental group and how to represent it? I suppose that it's not a free group. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The group is indeed not free as it contains the fundamental group of the Hawaiian earrings as a subgroup which is not a free group. Any reasonable description of it using only basic tools would be very difficult as it contains many many copies of the Hawaiian earrings which all interact in interesting ways.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed quite a bit [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/pi-1-mathbb-r2-mathbb-q2-is-uncountable) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67549/fundamental-group-of-r2-q2).

Comment: So does it means that it's so bad a constructing to have its fundamental group discussed?-_-|| And I haven't learnt anything on category theory yet. Could it be proved whether it's a free group or not? Anyway many thanks indeed.