# Proving that a fundamental group is uncountable

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given the space $\mathbb{R}^2 - \bigl(\{0\}\times\mathbb{Q}\bigr)$, I need to show that the fundamental group of this space is uncountable. I thought of taking two points $A=(x_0,y_0)$ in the area where $x_0 < 0$  and $B (x_1,y_1)$ where $x_1>0$, now i can find a path between them since I removed the rationals form the $y$ axis , I still can find an irrational point such that my path pass by this point, now I consider a loop from $A$ passing throughout $B$, I can find another loop also, my claim is that these two loops can't be homotopic but i can't really prove this last thing. Am I thinking in the right way? if anyone could correct me and help me finish the proof, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I edited your question somewhat. Using TeX properly, and using proper capitalization, will improve the ability of readers to understand your question, and will improve your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Thank you , it's just that I'm not used to writing in mathematical language ,i will learn it soon, thank you for your edit :) @LeeMosher

Comment: This is basically a repeat of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/pi-1-mathbb-r2-mathbb-q2-is-uncountable), to which Jeremy Hurwitz gave a very nice answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is basically correct. What you need to complete the proof is the concept of [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number). Given a closed path $p : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ based at $A$ and a point $C \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $C \not\in \text{image}(p)$, the winding number of $p$ around $C$ is an integer which I will denote $w(p;C)$. There are two propeties of winding number that you need:

1. For any two closed paths $p_0, p_1 :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ based at $A$ whose images do not contain $C$, if there is a path homotopy $h :[0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ from $p_0$ to $p_1$ such that $C \not\in \text{image}(h)$ then $w(p_0;C) = w(p_1;C)$.
2. Suppose $p :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a simple closed curve, and so by the [Jordan curve theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) there are two components of $\mathbb{R}^2 - \text{image}(p)$, a bounded component called its *inside* and an unbounded component called its *outside*. If $C$ is on the inside of $p$ then $w(p;C) = \pm 1$, whereas if $C$ is on the outside of $p$ then $w(p;C)=0$. (The difference between $+1$ and $-1$ depends intuitively on whether $p$ goes around $C$ in the counterclockwise or the clockwise direction, but that's not important for this question).

Now what you write can be completed as follows. Consider an interval $[u,v]$ with irrational endpoints $u,v$. Define a simple closed curve $p$ which starts at $A$, crosses the $y$-axis from left to right at the point $(0,u)$, and crosses back from right to left at the point $(0,v)$, before returning to $A$. It follows that for any rational number $c$, we have 
$$w(p;(0,c)) = 
\begin{cases}
\pm 1 & \text{if $u<c<v$} \\
0  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Also, since the image of each path homotopy misses the rational points on the $y$-axis, the number $w(p;(0,c))$ is an invariant of the path homotopy class of $p$ for each rational number $c$. Since there are uncountably many choices for the interval $[u,v]$, this proves that the fundamental group is uncountable.

Comment: i appreciate your help , but i don't really understand the last paragraph "also [..]" , and do you mean that if i took two closed paths , one will contain C and i can choose the other to not contain it ?and if so , will this prove that no two paths are homotopic ? i don't seem to understand @LeeMosher

Comment: @Butterfly: The "also" in that paragraph refers back to item 1: for each point $C \in \{0\} \times \mathbb{Q}$, and for each path homotopy $h : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2 - (\{0\}\times\mathbb{Q})$ from $p_0$ to $p_1$, $\text{image}(h)$ does not contain the point $C$, and therefore $w(p_0,C)=w(p_1,C)$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**
let $C_n$ be the circle of radius $\sqrt2/n$ center at $(0,\sqrt2/n)$... consider a homomorphism $R: \pi_1(X) \rightarrow \prod_\infty\mathbb{Z}$ to the direct
 product (not the direct sum)of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ s.t for every sequence of integers {$x_n$} we can construct a loop f:I$\rightarrow$X that wraps $x_n$ times the loop $C_n$ in the time interval [1-1/n,1-1/n+1]...and it is continuous since every neighbourhood of the base point $(0,0)$ in X contains all but finitely many circles...so $R$ is surjective... so $\pi_1(X)$ is uncountable.