# Is there a space with fundamental group isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, fundamental-groups

I am studying basic algebraic topology and all examples of fundamental groups $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z^n \times \mathbb{Z}} / n \mathbb{Z} $, $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ etc are somewhat discrete. I don't have a rigorous way of stating this right now, but basically they are countable. Moreover, neither is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, apart from rigorous treatment of why a circle has integers as its FG, there is a moral to it : you can't loop/unloop in fractions or in irrationals units; you either unloop or you didn't.

My question is, is there a space where you can have a FG that is not countable, or if possible is $\mathbb{R}$, so that you can loop or unloop continuously.

Term loop/unloop are used unrigorously.

Comment: The Hawaiian earring has uncountable fundamental group. If I'm not mistaken, something like: $$\pi_1(H) = \prod_\mathbb{N} \mathbb{Z}$$ There are more examples here on MSE,  e.g. here [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16948/775079 ]

Comment: Edit for the last comment - I think I am mistaken, and you can actually show that $$\prod_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} \subset \pi_1 (H) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Discrete" and "Countable" are two different things. There are certainly spaces with uncountable fundamental groups; you can achieve any cardinality you like. As for *discreteness*, by definition the fundamental group does not come endowed with any topology, so it is (again, by definition) discrete.

In fact, **every** group is the fundamental group of some space. So, yes, that includes $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (as discrete groups). See, for example, the [Classifying space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space), which has the added feature that its higher homotopy groups are trivial.

Comment: Can we get $\mathbb R$ as fundamental group without using the Axiom of Choice?

Answer (score 1):

One way to topologize $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ in a canonical way is to define it as $\pi_0$ of the loop space $\Omega(X, x_0)$. (Note that $\pi_0$ carries a canonical topology since $\pi_0(Y)$ is a set-theoretic quotient of $Y$.)

With this description, one thing you get immediately is that $\pi_1(X)$ has to be totally disconnected, so e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ won't show up. However, it doesn't need to be discrete -- I believe the Hawaiian earring is a counterexample.